# why the last geocoder call fail?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I [have](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHm6h/3/) this code :

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    var VettoreIndirizziStruttura = new Array();
    VettoreIndirizziStruttura.push("via ronchi 67 Foppolo Italia");
    VettoreIndirizziStruttura.push("piazza vittorio veneto 3 Carona Italia");
    VettoreIndirizziStruttura.push("via bianchi 22 Carona Italia");
    VettoreIndirizziStruttura.push("via san rocco 8 Branzi Italia");
    VettoreIndirizziStruttura.push("via cortivo 9 Foppolo Italia");
    VettoreIndirizziStruttura.push("via sponda 1 Valleve Italia");
    VettoreIndirizziStruttura.push("piazza umberto I° 23 Branzi Italia");
    VettoreIndirizziStruttura.push("via piave 2 Foppolo Italia");
    VettoreIndirizziStruttura.push("via arale San Simone Italia");
    VettoreIndirizziStruttura.push("via ronchi 53/61 Foppolo Italia");
    VettoreIndirizziStruttura.push("via tegia 5 Valleve Italia");
    VettoreIndirizziStruttura.push("via ronchi 81 Foppolo Italia"); 

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  

    var index=0;
    elaboraCoordinate(index);
    function elaboraCoordinate(index) {
        geocoder.geocode({ address: VettoreIndirizziStruttura[index] }, function(results, status) {
            CoordinateStruttura = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());

            console.log(index + " - " + VettoreIndirizziStruttura[index] + " - " + CoordinateStruttura);
            index++;
            if(index<VettoreIndirizziStruttura.length)
                elaboraCoordinate(index);
        });                
    }
</script>
```

the last geocoder fail. I get this error : *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null*. What am I wrong?

Comment: On what line does this error occur?

Comment: returning the result, so on `CoordinateStruttura = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());` : but it shouldn't be null that result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is OK - you got this error because of no results.
You should add following check:

```
geocoder.geocode({ address: VettoreIndirizziStruttura[index] }, function(results, status) {
    if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) { ... }
});
```

You can handle other statuses - here is [reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingStatusCodes).

Comment: No! I should get the result for last address : if you try it alone, it works. Why the 11° fails?

Comment: I mean, try only using VettoreIndirizziStruttura.push("via ronchi 81 Foppolo Italia"); : it works...

Comment: As I said - it fails because in 11 address you do not have any result. And then you try to access `[0]` index of null value so there appears JavaScript error and it crashes. If you add `if` statement as I wrote above, you can avoid this case and skip all operations for no-result case.

Comment: ? no man! Every time I access to `results[0].geometry.location` I get the values. Only on the last VettoreIndirizziStruttura[] it can't retrieve the values. That's the problem... :O

Comment: Ok, tell me then what status is returned for this last case ?

Comment: Status is OK on the first 11 records :) http://jsfiddle.net/ZHm6h/4/ (check the console, last value). For the 12°, I can't see, because result is null

Comment: With 12 attempt there is `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` status. Not OK. I've updated your jsfillde example with `console.log` before access to the `results`.

Comment: That's sucks! So there is no way to get more than 11 records... OMG... horrible....

Comment: Just add some tiny sleep between requests.

Comment: Yeah! `setTimeout(function() { geolocation() }, 100);` works :)